# What does IRS Letter 96C Mean when they say, "Determined no action is necessary on your account."

Tags: united-states, income-tax, income

I am trying to figure out what does it mean when you receive a letter from the IRS and it says:

Thank you for your correspondence received June 4, 2015.

We reviewed the information you provided and determined no action is necessary on your account.

It seems so vague to me and I am not comprehending, I do not understand the meaning of it.

Can you please break it down for me.

Thank you.

Comment: We need some context.  What did you say in your correspondence of June 4, 2015?  What is this case about?

Comment: Innocent Spouse Relief form 8875 was submitted on June 4, 2015. Saying I couldn't pay. Hardship. My husband and I divorced and I could not pay.

Comment: Hmm.  I would try to contact them and ask for clarification.  But my first guess would be to read it as "we have decided not to grant you relief; your liability is the same as it was before".

Comment: @NiviaDyall innocent spouse relief is not for the cases of hardship, it is for cases where a husband incurs liability without his wife knowing so that the wife won't be forced to pay for it.

Answer (score 9):

Correction after understanding what they were replying to: I think I now agree that the message is more precisely:

"We checked, and we see nothing unusual enough about your situation that it requires special treatment. The normal rules apply."

Since you were *asking* for special treatment,  this would seem to be bad news.

To be certain,  I think you'll need to contact them and ask for clarification.

Comment: You forgot to add "we're not going to charge you any money you don't already owe us".